# Get least row from group by

Tags: mysql

i have a table which i want to fetch min timstamp on the group by of _Uid and _status.

```
select _id, _Uid, max(_status) as _status, min(_timestamp) as _last_updated_ 
from table_name 
where 
group by _Uid, _status
```

**output**

```
_id     _Uid    _status _timestamp
17685   14635   21  2019-07-20 10:05:50
17167   14635   16  2019-07-16 07:42:54
17687   14635   12  2019-07-20 10:07:02
17020   14635   8   2019-07-15 08:46:08
17705   14640   13  2019-07-20 11:35:39
17706   14640   9   2019-07-20 11:36:15
17019   14640   8   2019-07-15 08:46:08
```

**preferred output**

```
_id     _Uid    _status _timestamp
17685   14635   21  2019-07-20 10:05:50
17705   14640   13  2019-07-20 11:35:39
```

This is one of my query i am using in join.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a subquery:

```
SELECT m._id,m._Uid,m._status, min(m._timestamp) AS _timestamt
  FROM(SELECT _id,_Uid,max(_status) as _status
         FROM mytable
         GROUP BY _Uid
      ) x
  JOIN mytable m ON m._id = x._id
    AND m._Uid = x._Uid
    AND m._status = x._status
  GROUP BY m._id,m._Uid,m._status
```

The idea is to use first the group by to evaluate the status and a second group by to get the timestamp.